# How to return the iterator to the previous line in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

I am processing 2 lines at a time. To do this I have a for loop using the enumerate:

```
for id, line in enumerate(file):
    if id % 2 == 0:
        line1 = line
        print("First line: ", line1)
    else:
        line2 = line
        print("Second line: ", line2)
        print("Both lines: ", line1 + line2)
```

Everything is working perfectly for this input:

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
```

and the output is:

```
First line: This is line 1
Second line: This is line 2
Both lines: This is line1 This is line2
```

**Problem:** i do not want to process lines start with `'_:'`. How can I do that? I can simply add a condition such as `if line.startswith('_:')` but now the iterator will be incremented anyway so if I have an input like this:

```
Line1
_:Anthing
Line2
```

`:_Anything` will be considered line 2, just by checking if it starts with `'_:'`, but since it starts with `'_:'`, I do not want to process it, I still want my second line to be Line2. So after checking the line, if it starts with a special character, how can I return the iterator back to the last line without special characters?

I this case I want the output to be:

```
First Line: Line1
_:Anything
Second Line: Line2
Both lines: Line1 Line2
```

Comment: I do not want to delete them, I want to print everything to the output, but lines without special characters, I want to add stuff to them.

Comment: Just keep a seperate counter variable that you increment ever time the line starts with `_`

Comment: @pault Then most of the file contents will have to be loaded into memory.

Comment: `enumerate` just needs an iterator; it doesn't have to be a concrete list. `enumerate(l for l in file if not l.startswith("-"))`.

Comment: Please see my desired output. I do not want to get rid of these lines. I still want to print them in their exact place but without processing.

Comment: @chepner then I will have a file without these lines which I do not want it like this

Comment: Your bigger problem is that you can't get both lines in the *same* iteration of your loop.

Comment: Exactly, so is there a way to do something like this ?

Comment: Yes; don't unconditionally set `line2` before checking the value of `line`. If I understand correctly, `line2` isn't simply a line for which the current value of `id` is odd.

Comment: That is true. Line 2 is odd lines. But when I check if the line2 starts with `_:` then the iterator will be increased and line 2 will be the next line which is even line.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you want to see each line of the file, but whether a line is even or odd depends as much on its value as its position in the file. We only want to make such an assignment *after* we check its prefix, perhaps with something like

```
parity = itertools.cycle([True, False])  # even, odd, even, odd, ...
for line in file:
    if line.startswith("_:"):
        print(line)
        continue
    if next(parity):
        line1 = line
        print("First line: {}".format(line1))
    else:
        line2 = line
        print("Second line: {}".format(line2))
        print("Both line: {}{}".format(line1, line2))
```

The infinite, alternating Boolean series `parity` replaces the line number you get from `enumerate`. It lets you wait until after you decide to use `line` to "ask" whether this is an even or odd line.

---

Another way to look at this is that your original code iterates over `parity` and `file` simultaneously, rather than advancing `parity` separately. You could rewrite your original code as

```
for is_even, line in zip(cycle([True, False], file):
    if is_even:
        line1 = line
        print("First line: ", line1)
    else:
        line2 = line
        print("Second line: ", line2)
        print("Both lines: ", line1 + line2)
```

and so see that my contribution is simply to replace the implicit call to `next(parity)` with an explicit, conditional call.

Comment: I like the cycle :)

Comment: Thank you so much!! That is appreciated!

Comment: +1 but cycle seems overkill to toggle the boolean, what’s wrong with ‘if parity: parity = not parity’ etc.?

Comment: I like streams and immutable state (when possible).

Answer (score 1):

You do not have "iterators" - you memorize single lines:

```
t = """Line1
_:Anthing1
Line2 
Line3
_:Anthing2
Line4"""

line1 = None   # these are not iterators, they are just lines
line2 = None   # same here, just one memorized line

# the index you get is not needed at all ...
for line in t.split("\n"):  # instead of "for line in file:"
    # base case
    if line.startswith("_:"):
        print(line) # no processing

    elif line1 is None and line2 is None:  # remember first line
        line1 = line
        print("First line: ", line1)

    elif line1 is not None: # we got a first line, so this is the second one
        line2 = line
        print("Second line: ", line2)
        print("Both lines: ", line1 + line2)

        # do processing on line1 and line2

        # reset memorized lines
        line1 = None
        line2 = None
```

Output:

```
First line:  Line1
_:Anthing1
Second line:  Line2 
Both lines:  Line1Line2 
First line:  Line3
_:Anthing2
Second line:  Line4
Both lines:  Line3Line4
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but it gave me this error: `for line in file.split("\n"):  \
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: `t.split("\n")` is just a stand-in for `file` in this answer, to provide a sequence of strings to iterate over.

Comment: @Lucas you can use `for _,line in enumerate(file):` and simply ignore the index - or use `for line in file:` - you might need to nix any `'\n'` on ends though when postprocessing the lines - play around.